# Extend line until new value occurs

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to extend the shorter line of a chart with 2 lines until the next value occurs. So we have to continuing lines. Is that possible?

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Step line ends prematurely'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [[0, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]],
            name: 'Longer'
        }, {
            data: [[0, 2], [1, 3]],
            name: 'Shorter'
        }]

    });
});
```

See jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/vCVhE/1/

Comment: You'll have to add a final point to the shorter series for the line to continue

Answer (score 0):

This problem strongly depends on how you intend to add new values, if it is always going to be only 2 lines and the second is always the shortest...

Anyway, I made this function to solve your specific shown problem, but I don't think it's going to be hard to adjust it to fit your specific situation:

```
// append point
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
var max_length1 = chart.series[0].data.length-1; //longer
var max_x1 = chart.series[0].data[max_length1].x;     
var max_length2 = chart.series[1].data.length-1; //shorter
var max_x2 = chart.series[1].data[max_length2].x;
var max_y2 = chart.series[1].data[max_length2].y;     
var delta_x = (max_x2-chart.series[1].data[max_length2-1].x);
var delta_y = (max_y2-chart.series[1].data[max_length2-1].y);
var new_y = max_y2+(delta_y/delta_x)*(max_x1-max_x2);

chart.series[1].addPoint([max_x1,new_y]);
```

[JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/vCVhE/2/)